# Local Notification on locked screen ios

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, localnotification

I want to send Local Notification when screen is locked in iOS.
Below is the code I've added.But unable to get notified when screen is locked

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertAction = "Go back to App"
notification.alertBody = "Phone Found..!!"

notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1) as Date
UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
```

Please suggest, what I'm missing.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `timeIntervalSinceNow: 1`, how are you able to run this code and within one second you lock your device? try increasing that and then try again... possibly it's getting fired when application is open

Answer (score 0):

Your code works put you must increase the time interval , `UILocalNotification` is deprecated use `UNUserNotificationCenter`

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert])
    { (success, error) in
        if success {
            print("Permission Granted")
        } else {
            print("There was a problem!")
        }
    }


    let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notification.title = "title"
    notification.subtitle = "subtitle"
    notification.body = "the body."

    let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification1", content: notification, trigger: notificationTrigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared UNUserNotificationCenter object to schedule local notifications.
You need to import Usernotifications framework into your swift file and then you can request the local notification.

```
import UserNotifications
```

And you need to call the function in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
registerForLocalNotifications()
```

Definition for  registerForLocalNotifications()

```
  func registerForLocalNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

        guard granted else {return}

        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}

func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else {return}

        // UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Then you can create content of notification and request for notification like this.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Title of Notification"
content.body = "Body of Notification"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()


let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 120, repeats: true)           


let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Identifier of notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
                    }
                })
```